# Creating value checker

Tags: javascript

I want to make a value checker, which would send me my defined response after submitting the value.
My requirements:

`If x = 1, x= 2, x=3, then I get response "Not passed"

If x = 4, x=5, x= 6, x= 7, x=8, x=9, x=10 response "passed!"

If x = 4-, x=5+, x=yes   response "not a number"

If x= 0, x= 11, x= -2 response "wrong data"

If x is empty (No data entered) response "there are no data!"
`

I am getting stuck when I have to define 4-, 5+, yes as my function is reading those numbers without + and - signs after them and is giving the answer "Passed" like for 4 and 5 without + and -, please check it, maybe you get some ideas how to fix it.

For full code: https://codesandbox.io/s/cocky-black-7mezc?file=/ifelse.html:0-2245
My code:

```html
<h2>Ievadi datus</h2>
<span contenteditable="true"><p id="ievad"></p></span>
<button id="poga1">Check!</button>
<h2>Rezultāts</h2>
<br />
<span contenteditable="true"><p id="izv">Vispirms ievadi datus!</p></span>
```

And Javascript:

```js
var rezultats = '';

document.getElementById('poga1').onclick = function () {
  let izv = document.getElementById('izv');
  let vertejums = document.getElementById('ievad');
  let rezultats = parseFloat(vertejums.textContent);
  return nep(rezultats);
};

function nep(rezultats) {
  if (rezultats <= 0 || rezultats > 10.0) {
    izvads = 'Wrong data';
  } else if (rezultats < 4.0) {
    izvads = 'Not passed!';
  } else if (rezultats <= 10.0) {
    izvads = 'Passed!';
  } else if ((rezultats == '4-', '5+', 'yes')) {
    izvads = "It's not a number!";
  } else {
    izvads = 'There are no data!';
  }

  izv = document.getElementById('izv');
  izv.innerHTML = izvads;
}
```

**Will be thankful for help!**

Answer (score 0):

```js
/*
`If x = 1, x= 2, x=3, then i get response "Not passed"

If x = 4, x=5, x= 6, x= 7, x=8, x=9, x=10 response "passed!"

If x = 4-, x=5+, x=yes response "not a number"

If x= 0, x= 11, x= -2 response "wrong data"

If x is empty (No data entered) response "there are no data!" `
*/

document.getElementById("input").addEventListener("change", function() {

  // default to no data
  let message = "there are no data!";
  const output = document.getElementById("output");

  // get the value, this will be text - trim all leading and trailing spaces 
  const value = this.value.trim();
  if (value !== "") {
    // try to convert it to an integer
    const numeric = parseInt(value);
    // check if it's a number and if it matches what was entered
    if (isNaN(numeric) || numeric != value) {
      message = "not a number";
    } else
    if (numeric >= 1 && numeric <= 3) {
      message = "not passed";
    } else if (numeric >= 4 && numeric <= 10) {
      message = "passed!";
    } else {
      message = "wrong data";
    }
  }
  output.textContent = message;
});
```

```html
<output id="output"></output><br>
<label for="input">Input</label>
<input type="text" id="input">
```

Comment: Thanks! It really works but i have a rule that i must keep my input as contenteditable paragraph and i need the button which will trigger the check. Is it possible to make your script with the button i had before?

Comment: Yes, the source of the data can be .textContent as you have it, instead of value.

Comment: I have tried changing your code to my old one but i was out of luck. Could you please look into it? Best regards.

Comment: I don’t have time right now, put the if statement in your new function, it should work fine. Change the variable names.

Comment: Was able to fix the issue. The problem was that i had to change value to innerHTML.